# Peculiar Japanese DNS arrangement

Tags: email, spam

I have been receiving spam emails on my many mails but specifically gmail from a `.jp` domain. I deleted the emails but today I decided to actually read one of those emails to see if they can send me my inheritance from this Nigerian prince via PayPal.

Anyway, I noticed the email was from a Japanese domain and I decided to follow the top level domain.

These are the screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

I went ahead and opened `ne.jp` and that redirected to `www.ne.jp`

That's where it got interesting and I now suspect they have no idea they are among the top mailers of spam worldwide.

The page reads:

> About www.ne.jp
>
> The name of this domain is www.ne.jp, NOT ne.jp. Japanese domain
>   names, like those of many countries other than the United States,
>   consist of three parts rather than just two (compare a typical
>   American domain like "aol.com"). We just happened to register the word
>   "WWW" as the private part of our name -- the Japanese equivalent to
>   the US domain www.net. In other words, the "WWW" part is not simply an
>   indicator of where the home page resides, as in most cases, but is
>   actually the name itself.
>
> Thus, if you are searching for information about a domain name of the
>   form foo.bar.ne.jp, where bar is not "WWW", you've come to the wrong
>   place. In particular, if someone has attacked you or spammed you from
>   such a domain, it has nothing to do with us. You can find more
>   information about the real culprit by looking up the name bar.ne.jp in
>   the WHOIS database at JPNIC, the Japan Network Information Center.

From the page,

> ...In particular, if someone has attacked you or spammed you from such
>   a domain, it has nothing to do with us.

Why do they say that while the mail `outpost@alpha.ocn.ne.jp` is part of `ne.jp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ne.jp` is not a domain name. It's a second-level TLD, similar to `co.uk`.

`outpost@alpha.ocn.ne.jp` is an email address under the domain `alpha.ocn.ne.jp`, which is a subdomain of [`ocn.ne.jp`](https://www.ocn.ne.jp/) -- a large Japanese Internet provider.

Comment: For similar questions it's always helpful to check the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/). The list contains the domain parts where users can register subdomains below. Of course it contains `ne.jp` and also many other similar subdomains like `ed.jp` or `lg.jp`

Comment: As a slightly different example, this is kind of like the `.co.uk` that you see on a lot of British sites.  Many (but not most) countries outside the US do this with their TLD's so that they can still sort sites by type without having to use the (potentially expensive and largely American controlled) older TLD's like `.com` and `.org`.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn …that’s exactly the example I gave in my answer.

Comment: @duskwuff And now I feel like an idiot, because I somehow completely missed that...